# add_header directive not honored by nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm overlooking something very simple here. Using the following configuration, the header set with add_header never materializes. I tried adding it to both server clauses as well with the same effect. version is 1.19.2

```
server {
    listen              443 default_server ssl;
    listen              [::]:443 default_server ssl;
    server_name         _;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/some.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/some.key;
}

server {
    listen      443;
    server_name wiki.some.com;
    location / {
        add_header  X-Upstream  "test123";
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.4:80;
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, I'm using the following bit of php to display headers received at the server:

```
<?php
$headers =  getallheaders();
foreach($headers as $key=>$val){
  echo $key . ': ' . $val . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Use `curl --head https://wiki.some.com` to see the headers if you can in your OS.

Answer (score 1):

A **very** common beginners mistake. `add_header` directive is used for adding additional headers to the response nginx send as an answer to user's browser request. If you want to add aditional headers to the proxied request going to some backend use [`proxy_set_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) directive.